# how to add text to speech in broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

```
I'm doing a POC on text to speech.
```

There is a condition that when ever the device gets a new SMS in  inbox a text speech should tell the user that "You have received a new message".But text to speech is not working on loading or listening.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{
    TextToSpeech t1;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";        
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }    

    }


    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
              int result = t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
              if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                  Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
              }
              speakOut();
            } else {
              Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
    }

    private void speakOut() {
          t1.speak("You have one new message would you like to read it", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
      }
}
```

This is my sms receiver method.
Here i can send and receive SMS properly but after reading the message the text speech is not working could anyone give a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs. First of all t1 is null, so you will get NPE, and the other thing is that You shouldn't do heavy duty tasks in broadcast receiver, fire an IntentService instead nad speak from there. Also remember to call the constructor. Details here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#TextToSpeech(android.content.Context, android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener)

Answer (score 0):

For the `onInit()` method to be invoked, you have to initialize the object of `TextToSpeech` as shown below:

```
t1 = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```